# Mockito: given versus when

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, bdd

In order to stub methods when using JUnit and Mockito, it's possible to use two ways:

```
when(foo.doSomething()).thenReturn(somethingElse);
```

and

```
given(foo.doSomething()).willReturn(somethingElse);
```

Are there any differences between these two stubs?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Mockito syntax.

From my point of view these are just different styles. The first is the normal Mockito syntax and the second just tries to fit nicer into BDD style tests - I really like the second version because it reads so nicely in BDD tests.

Comment: For ease of clicking: [Main docs BDD refererence](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#29) and [BDDMockito docs](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/BDDMockito.html)